# Sort wp_nav_menu() by menu order

Tags: menus, admin, wp-admin, order

I have made a custom menu handler for the back end, sorting the via a drag drop based on [CMS Page Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-page-order/).

The problem now is that it seems that it's not possible to sort wp_nav_menu in any other way than the default one, can that be really be true?

Comment: Show us what you have tried already to make answers possible.

Comment: @toscho I am yet to find something to try out, the only code I've found is the one that reverses the array, not quite what I'm looking for. Maybe it's possible to do something in the walker, but it's too complex for me to understand (it's from the roots framework: http://pastebin.com/W5ja5dGJ)

Comment: @toscho I also found this, but not really sure if it applies to my problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52408/2830 Tried this to no avail: http://pastebin.com/5NHqC2S1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The nav_menu_items are already sorted by menu_order.

When you go into the Appearance -> Menus and arrange the order menu the menu_order of each menu item gets updated.

To change the orderby parameter in the query that displays the menu you can use pre_get_posts to alter it.  Example:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_sort_nav' );
function wpse_sort_nav( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'nav_menu_item' )
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'ID' );
    }
```

ID and menu_order are your only real options for sorting using the default post table.  There is no title and the post_name is the same as the ID.

You could add additional parameters to the pre_get_posts filter using the meta data stored with each nav_menu_item.

Nav Menu metadata:

_menu_item_menu_item_parent
_menu_item_type
_menu_item_object_id
_menu_item_object
_menu_item_target
_menu_item_classes
_menu_item_xfn
_menu_item_url